# Unable to get module for managing windows system working in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am learning ansible. My laptop is running Windows 7 and is part of a domain. I have installed Ubuntu linux inside a VM on my laptop and installed Ansible in it, and other python and kerberos packages. Have also configured kerberos but unable to use windows modules to even ping my laptop using win_ping. Ansible I think is still trying to use ssh instead of winrm.

Have added user and password info in group_vars/windows.yml file. Domain is lab.test.com

The message I get when running the command `ansible laptop -m win_ping -vvvvv`

```
Loaded callback minimal of type stdout, v2.0
<laptop.lab.test.com> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<laptop.lab.test.com> SSH: ansible.cfg set ssh_args: (-o)(ControlMaster=auto)(-o)(ControlPersist=60s)
<laptop.lab.test.com> SSH: ansible_password/ansible_ssh_pass not set: (-o)(KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no)(-o)(PreferredA
uthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey)(-o)(PasswordAuthentication=no)
<laptop.lab.test.com> SSH: ANSIBLE_TIMEOUT/timeout set: (-o)(ConnectTimeout=10)
<laptop.lab.test.com> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_common_args: ()
<laptop.lab.test.com> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_extra_args: ()
<laptop.lab.test.com> SSH: found only ControlPersist; added ControlPath: (-o)(ControlPath=/home/vagrant/.ansible/cp/ansibl
e-ssh-%h-%p-%r)
<laptop.lab.test.com> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no
 -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPa
th=/home/vagrant/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r U0128159-TPL-B.ten.thomsonreuters.com '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 22 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOM
E/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1462196365.95-235238773027827 `" && echo "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1462196365.95-235238773027827 `"
)'"'"''

laptop.lab.test.com | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

The web page I am following is [How To Setup An Ansible Test Lab For Windows Managed Nodes & Custom Windows Modules](http://darrylcauldwell.com/how-to-setup-an-ansible-test-lab-for-windows-managed-nodes-custom-windows-modules/)

I have googled but unable to find, yet, the issue I am facing. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Post your `windows.yml`. Did you set ` ansible_connection: winrm` in your `windows.yml` For debugging purposes you could try to add `--extra-vars=ansible_connection: winrm` to your Ansible command to make sure it uses `winrm` connection and not ssh.

Comment: Thanks @knowhy. I had already figured it out and will be posting a step-by-step guide that others may find useful.

Answer (score 0):

To Solve this error, you have to specify few arguments in all.yml file to authenticate user in windows. also you need to install pywinrm module using pip.

```
pip install pywinrm
```

This is a must package to be installed on your controller machine.

```
ansible_user: Administrator
ansible_password: SecretPasswordGoesHere
ansible_port: 5986
ansible_connection: winrm
```

But as you are using kerberos for authentication, you can remove `ansible_password` and user kinit for creating ticket.

if your org. using a domain then you need to add that in your `ansible_user:user@domain.com` to work.

Answer (score -1):

There were quite a few things that I had to modify here and there. I wrote all that I did to properly configure the management and other nodes as I did not find proper steps in a single place. Documented all the steps I did to make windows work properly with Ansible - https://aseemkblog.wordpress.com/2016/06/01/configuring-ansible-to-manage-windows-system-over-powershell/.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Hi @jscott, I get your point. I did a lot of things which ultimately got it working, hence not one single answer that I could post saying this particular step got the issue sorted out. There were firewall issues, kerberos issues, etc, so I posted that link. Thanks.